# Why waste server resournces on validating Facebook SSL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was rewriting the Facebook's PHP-SDK 3.1.1 & I've noticed the `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt`. The latter is used in CURL requests to validate the SSL certificate.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt');
```

Why simply not set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `0`. Since all the requests are made to one of the following hosts we can safely rely on them?

```
'api'       => 'https://api.facebook.com/',
'api_video' => 'https://api-video.facebook.com/',
'api_read'  => 'https://api-read.facebook.com/',
'graph'     => 'https://graph.facebook.com/',
'www'       => 'https://www.facebook.com/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't have enough rep to comment, so re-answering)

As Tass's answer says, SSL aims to prevent both passive and active eavesdropping. Thwarting passive eavesdropping is fairly simple to accomplish - unauthenticated Diffie-Hellman key agreement will do the trick. An active attack is a bit harder to deal with since they could just pretend to be the server to the client and vice-versa allowing them to proxy all traffic. Certificates address this by providing a means of establishing identity of one or both parties in a way that an active attacker cannot (in theory) spoof.

MitM attacks are *not* limited to WiFi networks. If your server is on a subnet with other servers (it probably is), someone with access to a machine in the same subnet could do an [ARP spoofing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) to intercept all traffic between your server and the router. Anyone with access to your ISP's network gear could also do a MitM - do you trust your ISP to never get hacked? Finally, there are [ASN hijack attacks](http://www.omninerd.com/articles/Did_China_Hijack_15_of_the_Internet_Routers_BGP_and_Ignorance) where someone could intercept all traffic in and out of facebook and do what they please with it.

Realistically, if you disable certificate validation, it's unlikely that anything bad will happen. It's also unlikely that anything bad will happen if drive without a seatbelt or ride a bicycle without a helmet. Is saving a millisecond or two per request worth it?

Answer (score 4):

The man-in-the-middle attack (often abbreviated MITM, also known as a bucket brigade attack, or sometimes Janus attack) in cryptography and computer security is a form of active eavesdropping in which the attacker makes independent connections with the victims and relays messages between them, making them believe that they are talking directly to each other over a private connection, when in fact the entire conversation is controlled by the attacker. The attacker must be able to intercept all messages going between the two victims and inject new ones, which is straightforward in many circumstances (for example, an attacker within reception range of an unencrypted Wi-Fi wireless access point, can insert himself as a man-in-the-middle). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: Uh. Where did my comments disappear? Anyway, my point is that MITM is likely to happen in WI-FI network. However, here we are talking about ISP contacting directly to Facebook servers. There isn't anywhere for MITM to occur, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

To spot somebody pretending to be Facebook?